# nodejs - npm install dependency if module doesn't exist in parent

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash

I have a use case where my project has dependency on Lodash, and then there are other node_modules which further have dependency on Lodash.

When I do 'npm install' on my project. Lodash gets installed two times,
one for my 'project/node_modules/lodash' and second for my dependency 'project/node_modules/dependency-1/node_modules/lodash'.

I am thinking if it is possible to have 'lodash' dependency installed in my project's root only? When that happens, my dependency will try to load parent's node_module/lodash instead of its own.

This should save me some Module loading in memory.

Sine Module caching is based on FilePath, I don't want to keep two instances of Lodash loaded in memory, one for parent directory and one for dependency itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npm dedupe`. It will flatten up your dependencies by moving them up in the tree where possible.

See docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

There is an [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6912) which address this.